# Installing QuoteRoom and TradeStation on separate PCs

Tags: networking, home-networking, remote-access

I have a single Windows XP PC running [QuoteRoom and TradeStation](http://www.forexite.com/) (note, source is in Russian). QuoteRoom gets forex data from the internet, and TradeStation takes the data from QuoteRoom for visualisation and reports.

QuoteRoom can act as a server so that it can reside on a different PC to Tradestation, and so I am planning to install QuoteRoom on a different machine, then configure TradeStation to access it across the local network.

In QuoteRoom, there is the following screen which shows the server configuration:

[image: QuoteRoom Portal server]

I would like to understand how to configure this screen once the QuoteRoom software is installed on the new PC.

Also, I would like to be able to remove the screen from this PC once this is setup, so I will need remote access.

Do I enable this on the new PC or the existing PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows the IP address and port that the QuoteRoom software should listen on in order to accept connections from TradeStation clients.

You would normally only need to change this if the QuoteRoom server had multiple IP addresses.  In this case, if there is only one IP address on the PC that will be running QuoteRoom, then it can be left at the default.  When you configure the TradeStation to obtain its data from the new QuoteRoom PC, you will use the same IP and port that the new PC displays in this screen.

If you wish to access the QuoteRoom server using Remote Desktop, then it is the QuoteRoom server that should have Remote Desktop enabled.